# Exclude viewing of a field in a view for a content type without excluding content

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have 3 types of content (article, product, service) and a view that displays my content on a page.

In my view I added :

- a title field
- a description field
- a content type field

How do I display all the contents in my view by excluding the display of the "content type" field only on the content type "article" (I do not want to exclude the "article" from my view, only the field) ?

I want "product" and "service" to display the "content type" field.

I do not want "article" to display the "content type"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional).

I have added some random image from the web, just for reference purposes.

**If this field...** `Content type`

**Is...** `Not equal to`

**This value** `Article`

**Then output this...** `[type]`

**Otherwise, output this...** (leave empty/blank)

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I still have a problem